# Conditional if statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Instead of writing long 'if' statement, I would like to store that in some variable then pass it into 'if' condition.
For example:

```
tempvar = '1 >0 and 10 > 12'
if tempvar:
   print something
else:
     do something
```

Does it possible in python ?

Thanks for your suggestion but my problem is something else which I can't figure out.
I am doing multi string search in text file and trying to convert multi string into one condition:

```
    allspeciesfileter=['Homo sapiens', 'Mus musculus', 'Rattus norvegicus' ,'Sus scrofa']
    multiequerylist=[]

    if len(userprotein)> 0:
        multiequerylist.append("(str("+ "'"+userprotein+ "'"+")).lower() in (info[2].strip()).lower()")
    if len(useruniprotkb) >0:
        multiequerylist.append("(str("+ "'"+useruniprotkb+ "'"+")).lower() in (info[3].strip()).lower()")
    if len(userpepid) >0:
        multiequerylist.append("(str("+ "'"+userpepid+ "'"+")).lower() in (info[0].strip()).lower()")
    if len(userpepseq) >0:
        multiequerylist.append("(str("+ "'"+userpepseq+ "'"+")).lower() in (info[1].strip()).lower()")


    multiequery =' and '.join(multiequerylist)

    for line in pepfile:
        data=line.strip()
        info= data.split('\t')
        tempvar = bool (multiquery)
        if tempvar:
           do something
```

But that multiquery is not working

Comment: The result of the expression `(1 > 0) and (10 > 12)` is a boolean value, so just store that in a variable. I.e. you're almost there, just don't turn the expression into a string (for whatever reason you did that).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and I didn't know if condition use boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend avoiding this in production code, due to performance, security and maintenance issues, but you can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) to convert your strings to an actual bool value:

```
string_expression = '1 >0 and 10 > 12'
condition = eval(string_expression)
if condition:
   print something
else:
   do something
```

Answer (score 6):

Just drop the string and store the condition in the variable.

```
>>> condition = 1 > 0 and 10 > 12
>>> if condition:
...    print("condition is true")
... else:
...    print("condition is false")
...
condition is false
```

You can even store a more complex condition with (for example) lambda

Here's random example using lambda with something a little more complex

(although using BS for parsing this is a bit overkill)

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = "<a href='#' class='a-bad-class another-class another-class-again'>a link</a>"
>>> bad_classes = ['a-bad-class', 'another-bad-class']
>>> condition = lambda x: not any(c in bad_classes for c in x['class'])
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> anchor = soup.find("a")
>>> if anchor.has_attr('class') and condition(anchor):
...    print("No bad classes")
... else:
...    print("Condition failed")
Condition failed
```

Comment: Thanks and it is really awesome. But I have updated my problem in details and this solution still not working for my case

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 1 > 0 and 10 > 12
False
>>> '1 > 0 and 10 > 12'
'1 > 0 and 10 > 12'
>>> stringtest = '1 > 0 and 10 > 12'
>>> print(stringtest)
1 > 0 and 10 > 12
>>> if stringtest:
...     print("OK")
... 
OK
>>> 1 > 0 and 10 < 12
True
>>> booleantest = 1 > 0 and 10 < 12
>>> print(booleantest)
True
>>>
```

The string type is True. You should drop the single quotes.